# Usage of CScrollView in MFC application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am using CSCrollView window for our Application in which i have table drawn in View.
I have derived the CMYclass from CSCrollView, But whenevr i am scrolling the window up and down whatever i have drwan is getting erased. How i can acheive it this... i need to perform same actvity like a Word Pad is doing with images and Text. I want to keep scroll  the View Vertically. Till the page ends.

Here is the code snippet:-

```
void CMyView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
     CSize sizeTotal;
     // TODO: calculate the total size of this view
     sizeTotal.cx = 450;
    sizeTotal.cy = 700;
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, sizeTotal);
} 

void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    for(int i = 1;i<50;++i)
    {
        AddRow(pDC);
        TopPos = Height+TopPos;//  ![Outpu Window Image][1]
        nCountRow++;
    }
}
```

it is only drawing 18 rows, but when iam scrolling down above drawn content is no more and also there is nothing coming up in scrolled area.

Is there anything more need to add?

Thanking for help

Regards,

Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

Long time I have used `CScrollView`. Here is my hint: Try mapping modes other than `MM_TEXT`. Also look up other functions in `CScrollView`. I suggest to draw simple stuff first than some complicated *rows.*